# How to build a Map using a list?

Tags: list, dictionary, ocaml

I have a node type like the following :

```
type position = float * float
type node = position
```

I created those modules for the Map :

```
module MyMap =
  struct
  type t = node
  let compare (a1,b1) (a2,b2) =
    if a1 > a2 then 1 
     else if a1 < a2 then -1
     else if b1 > b2 then 1
       else if b1 < b2 then -1 

       else 0
  end


module DistMap = Map.Make(MyMap)
```

I have written this function to add elements to my map.

```
let init_dist nodes source =
  let testMap = DistMap.empty in
  let rec init_dist_aux nodes map source =
    match nodes with
    | [] -> map
    | x::tl -> if x = source then map = DistMap.add x 0. map else map = DistMap.add x max_float map;
    init_dist_aux tl map source
  in init_dist_aux nodes testMap source
```

The output was :

```
Characters 160-186:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
val init_dist : node list -> node -> float DistMap.t = <fun>
```

I tried this :

```
let initMap = init_dist nodes (4.67521849144109414,6.85329046476252568);;
```

However init_dist has type unit, so I was unable to create the Map.

My goal is to be able to use this function to build a map.

Comment: look into dict comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lays in the code below :

```
match nodes with
| [] -> map
| x::tl -> if x = source then map = DistMap.add x 0. map else map = DistMap.add x max_float map;
init_dist_aux tl map source
```

Around the 2 pieces of code :

```
map = DistMap.add...
```

This is a comparison (and so a boolean) not an assignement as you might wish to implement.
You have to first evaluate `map via`let and then process init_dist_aux with new map. Or, since the only difference is the 2nd value (0. or max_float), you can first evaluate this second argument, then process the whole thing as below:

```
match nodes with
| [] -> map
| x::tl -> let v = if (x = source) 
               then        0. 
               else max_float 
           in 
               init_dist_aux tl (Dist.add x v map) source
```